# cdf of autocorrelation statistic, null hypothesis is uniform distribution

Tags: autocorrelation, cumulative-distribution-function

Suppose I carry out $N$ observations $X_1,...,X_N$. The null hypothesis will be that these are sampled iid from $U(0,1)$. I would like to check whether observations a distance $k$ apart are correlated. According to Wikipedia, the statistic I should look at is:

$\hat{R}(k)=\frac{12}{N-k}\sum_{i=1}^{N-k}(X_i-\frac{1}{2})(X_{i+k}-\frac{1}{2})$

It's clear that $E[\hat{R}(k)]=0$. Large values of this statistic, either positive or negative, are evidence against the null hypothesis.

But I'd like to be more specific and get p-values. That is, I'd like to find the cdf of $\hat{R}(k)$. If I could and I called this function $F$, the p-value corresponding to $\hat{R}(k)=x$ would be $1-[F(|x|)-F(-|x|)]$.

I was wondering whether there's an explicit formula, in terms of $N$ and $k$, for the cdf of this statistic.

Thanks

Edit: Here's some partial work. Clearly if $X\sim U(0,1)$, then $X-\frac{1}{2}\sim U(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. For notational simplicitly, let's just call this $X$. Suppose $Y$ is the product of two different copies of $X$. Then $Y$ may take on values between $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$. To work out the pdf of $Y$, note that if $x_1x_2=y$ and both $|x_i|\leq\frac{1}{2}$, then both $|x_i|\geq 2|y|$. So at any point other than $y=0$:

$f_Y(y)=\int_{-1/2}^{-2|y|}f_X(u)f_X(y/u)du+\int_{2|y|}^{1/2}f_X(u)f_X(y/u)du$

The expressions inside both integrals are 1, so:

$f_Y(y)=2(\frac{1}{2}-2|y|)=1-4|y|$ for $-\frac{1}{4}\leq y\leq\frac{1}{4}$

(Technically I should check that nothing weird happens to the cdf at $y=0$, but let's let that slide)

Clearly this is symmetric about 0, hence has expectation 0. So each term in the sum has expectation 0. Thus $\hat{R}(k)$ has expectation 0.

To finish the problem, I need to work out the pdf of the sum of $N-k$ copies of $Y$. Unfortunately, this is more complicated, not just because I have to deal with $N-k$ copies instead of $2$, but because of partial dependencies between the copies. Going back to the original notation, $X_1-\frac{1}{2}$ and $X_N-\frac{1}{2}$ show up in only one term, but those in the middle may show up in up to two terms. So I was wondering whether this has already been worked out and there's a standard formula somewhere.

Comment: @epp That shouldn't be right. The product of two independent copies of the same random variables is not the same thing as that random variable squared. The former will never be negative, while the latter may be. 

I'll add some partial work to my question.

Comment: ah right, good point

Comment: It's not clear this is a great statistic to analyze.  Because your assumptions are so strong and specific, you could replace the $X_i$ by $Y_i=\Phi^{-1}(X_i),$ the standard Normal quantiles associated with the $X_i,$ and instead use their autocorrelation proportional to $\sum Y_iY_{i+k},$ thereby reducing the problem to the standard textbook situation.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the reply and sorry for the slow response. What is the standard textbook situation?

Comment: Look up uses of the ACF (autocorrelation function).